How can I call a method inside another signal store method
I have a signal store with method loadItems() and a method countItems(). loadItems should call countItemsat the end of its operation. How is that possible? Is that possible at all. And would that also work with rxMethods?
stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-b9xpmc?file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fsample-store.ts
This is the store:
export const sampleStore = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },

  withState({
    items: [] as string[],
    itemCount: 0,
  }),

  withMethods((store) => ({
    loadItems: () => {
      patchState(store, { items: ['one', 'tow', 'three'] });
      // countItems(); // Not possible
    },
    countItems: () => {
      patchState(store, { itemCount: store.items().length });
    },
  }))
);

And this is the component:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div>Items: {{sampleStore.items()}}</div>
    <div>ItemCount: {{sampleStore.itemCount()}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  sampleStore = inject(sampleStore);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sampleStore.loadItems();
    // this.sampleStore.countItems();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

If you un-comment this.sampleStore.countItems(); the expected happens. But I would like to call countItems() at the end of loadItems().

Please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz or github repo,for reference.

Hi Narren! I have updated the description.

Yes it is possible, just change your code to the following
withMethods((store) => {
 function countItems() {
  patchState(store, { itemCount: store.items().length });
 }

 function loadItems() {
  patchState(store, { items: ['one', 'tow', 'three'] });
  countItems(); // It is  possible Now
 }
 return {loadItems, countItems}
})


Cool. It did work, once I put '()' after the function names :-)

Great, I have fixed it

Here is one of the methods to achieve this, we can use withComputed to define computed signals, that will auto update when the source list reference changes (Arrays are stored as memory references).
export const sampleStore = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },

  withState({
    items: [] as string[],
    itemCount: 0,
  }),

  withMethods((store) => ({
    loadItems: () => {
      patchState(store, { items: ['one', 'tow', 'three'] });
    },
    countItems: () => {
      patchState(store, { itemCount: store.items().length });
    },
  })),
  withComputed(({ items }) => ({
    itemCount: computed(() => items().length),
  }))
);

Reference:
The new NGRX Signal Store for Angular: 3+n Flavors

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks, but i wanted to call a merhod, not implement something in a computed function. Then real problem i want solve is re-using a rxMeothod that is quite involved.

@JohannesSchacht did you figure this out? I am having the same issue, wanna call one rxmethod within the tapResponse of another

Finally found a solution.
The issue is, how to observe a signal inside the store.
witdhHooks -> onInit() and toObservable() do the trick.
    withHooks((store) => {
        return {
            onInit() {
                toObservable(store.items).subscribe(() => store.countItems());
            },
        };
    })


Check my answer, you don't need to do that in hooks
